# Proper way for concatenating 2 or more .js files into one in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

Suppose I have:

- common.js
- scriptA.js
- scriptB.js

And suppose that both scriptA and scriptB require functions that are in common.js
Instead of copy-pasting common.js in both files, I would like to send a concatenation of common+scriptA and common+scriptB as needed.

I don't want to do `$.getScript(...` because that would cause another request for getting the script.

How do I do this?
Is there a better way!?

Comment: Is this a one shot deal? Or are these files not necessarily required in the triad? If they will be required to work in conjunction over multiple pages, I'd suggest compiling them with closure or some other js compiler.

Comment: No, scriptA.js is used only in one page. The same for scriptB.js. common.js may be used by many more scripts.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress